# Internet Explorer and CSS transform value of scale on keyframes

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have built this awesome css only loader and everything is working fine except in Internet Explorer. For some reason, IE feels as if it needs to constantly shake. When it comes down to it all I'm doing is a simple keframe animation like this:

```
@keyframes loading
  0%
    transform: scale(1)
  50%
    transform: scale(1.2)
  100%
    transform: scale(1)
```

Here is my CodePen for the loader: http://codepen.io/MrGrigri/pen/zxWQdb

Also, here is the blog associated with it: http://codepen.io/MrGrigri/blog/responsive-loader/

In all of the other browsers its working like a champ...just not IE.

I'm testing it in IE Version 11.0.16 on Windows 8.1

Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I've tested in IE10 and works good but in IE 11 is 'shaking'. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having this same problem in IE 11, I could realize that if I reduce the time of the animation could works (ex. 0.3s). But that wasn't a solution for me.

While I was reading [How to fix shaking CSS transitions in Firefox](http://gielberkers.com/how-to-fix-shaking-css-transitions-in-firefox/) I found one solution (for Firefox), and I thought that could work the same concept for IE.

The idea is rotate (the minimum possible) the `div` or image while your making the scale. Just like this:

```
@keyframes loading
  0%
    transform: scale(1);
  50%
    transform: scale(1.2) rotate(0.02deg);
  100%
    transform: scale(1);
```

I made this trick and works in IE 11.

Comment: Thank you so much Jabel Márquez! This is a life saver. Muchas gracias Jabel Márquez! Este es un protector de la vida.

Comment: I'm glad this help to you @MrGrigri !